# Chef is not creating log files

Tags: chef-infra, kibana

I am new chef and I am writing cookbook to install and configure Kibana. I want log files to be generated.
I created kibana.service template which is also supposed to generate log file. Recipe creates kibana.service file and it starts service successfully but it does not generate log files.I want logs in data_hdd directory. Recipe has read/write permission on this directory.So I don't think "permission" is an issue.
It will be a big help if someone guide me through this

Thank you so much in advance

This is my code to create kibana.service file and template file.

```
template "/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service" do
    source 'kibana.service.erb'
    variables(
      directory: base_directory,
      command: "/bin/sh -ce '#{base_directory}/bin/kibana 2> 
    /data_hdd/kibana-logs/kibana-stderr.log 1> 
    /data_hdd/kibana-logs/kibana-stdout.log'"
    )
    end

code for kibana.service.erb template

[Unit]
Description=Install Kibana
Documentation=https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/5.6/index.html


[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=<%= @command %>
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
StartLimitBurst=3
StartLimitInterval=400

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the community kibana cookbook : https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/kibana5

Here is the code from my wrapper cookbook that uses the kibana5_configure resource :

```
kibana5_configure 'kibana' do
  svc_name 'kibana'
  template_cookbook "yp_elk"
  configuration 'server.port' => node["yp_kibana_configuration"]["port"],
                'server.host' => node[:ipaddress],
                'server.name' => node[:hostname],
                'logging.dest' => node["yp_kibana_configuration"]["log_location"],
                'logging.verbose' => node["yp_kibana_configuration"]["verbose"]
end
```